# Setting thresholds/limits to plotly graphs

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I am plotting a simple time based graph using ploltyjs. Could there be a way to set a threshold of sorts and maybe add an event that gets triggered when the threshold is exceeded.
Using the first example provided at https://plot.ly/javascript/time-series/ as a reference.

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
    var data = [{
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 3, 6],
    type: 'scatter'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {
    showSendToCloud: true
});
  </script>
</body>
```

Codepen link https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/KpYgpy

Comment: Welcome axel. Would you mind clarifying in your question on which data the threshold should be applied? Do you want a date limit? Or to limit the y values?

Comment: I took the liberty to remove your code pen link in favour of stack overflow's own editor. There were no dependencies any ways.